# TPL: check if task was faulted in OnCompleted event

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have a task like:

```
var migrateTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do stuff
     });

migrateTask.ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(this.MigrationProcessCompleted);
```

How to tell in the method `MigrationProcessCompleted` if I got an exception or task was faulted in the initial thread (in do stuff code block)?

Is there a way to find this without making the task a class member/property?

Comment: Why are you getting the awaiter and not using Task.ContinueWith?

Comment: because I need to execute MigrationProcessCompleted in the UI thread

Comment: And can you use `await`?

Comment: yes, I can use. This is my first experience with task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be really calling `.GetAwaiter()` it is intended for compiler use.

If you can use `await` your code is as simple as

```
public async Task YourFunc()
{

    Exception error = null
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //do stuff
         });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex;
    }

    MigrationProcessCompleted(error)
}

private void MigrationProcessCompleted(Exception error)
{
     //Check to see if error == null. If it is no error happend, if not deal withthe error.
}
```

Comment: In this case, in the code inside the run block throws an exception, will it be caught in the catch block? Because I've heard that the exception is not thrown when it occurs...

Comment: the `await` causes it to get caught by the catch block. if you had done `Task.Run` with no `await` then you would be correct.